# Ember 2, PERFORMANCES DILEMMA, computed properties in route or controller?

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using Ember 2.14.1.

Is it better that computed properties and something like that (until routeable components land) is on route or in a controller?

For performances reasons I mean. Is there any difference?

Comment: The route is not connected to templates, so if you put a computed property there, it will not be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

No performance reason. For the most part, you should define computed properties in Component(s) and pass down your data from the route into the components (could be via a Controller or just in the template "directly"). I would think there are very few cases where a computed property would be useful in a route. You *can* also use Controller(s) and define your computed properties there because the "context" of a rendered template is a Controller (whether you define one explicitly or not).